# SQL INSERT INTO query copy 3 x times

Tags: sql-server

I have a `MASTER` table and I'd like to `INSERT INTO` another table so a straight forward copy. I want to copy this table `3 x` times by changing the value of `1 x` field called `COMP` (short for company). In the `MASTER` table the field `COMP` contains value `MASTER`. I'd like to change this value to the `3 x` new companies `A, B & C`.

How & where in the query do I do this?

Much appreciated any assistance!

Comment: Are these companies coming from a different table, or are they hardcoded values?

Comment: Hiya Erik - They are hardcoded so written in the query

Comment: any your previous try

Comment: Hiya Nazir - I am relatively new to sql. I can do the basic INSERT INTO but not certain how I can change the value of the field so it copies the table 3 x times - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say you have the following table with values and one more table with same schema called AnotherTable

```
create table MasterTable(
   COMP varchar(50),
   MoreData varchar(200)
);
```

And you have the 3 values:

```
declare @Comp1 varchar(50) = 'AComp', @Comp2 varchar(50) = 'BComp', @Comp3 varchar(50) = 'CComp';

insert into AnotherTable
select @Comp1, MoreData
from MasterTable
union all 
select @Comp2, MoreData
from MasterTable
union all
select @Comp3, MoreData
from MasterTable
```

Now there still be issues of what are your Primary Key, Clustered Index.
Do you have identity in these tables or what is the identifier.
If the tables are huge you will need to do it in 3 inserts

```
insert into AnotherTable
select @Comp1, MoreData
from MasterTable;

insert into AnotherTable
select @Comp2, MoreData
from MasterTable;

insert into AnotherTable
select @Comp3, MoreData
from MasterTable;
```

Comment: Thanks Liya - will give the union all a go.  I did think I may have to do it 3 times - thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Liya - I did your last advice and worked :) - Thank you!